# Detect if flash need networking

Tags: flash

Is there any way to find if particular flash file need networking ? We plan to setup 'allowNetworking' 'none' for all flash assets (we have really **large number** of them, so start/sniff would not work), but have to find out which ones can be affected.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that because if an SWF needs networking to work correctly you should allow networking otherwise there is no problem ! Could you explain why you need that ? Maybe you are using external SWFs and for some security reasons you need that, I don't know ...

Comment: yes, external swfs, and yes, for security reason. @akmozo

Comment: What happened to the decompile & **grep** idea you came up with in the comments (of my now deleted answer)? I removed it cos it seemed you had found your own working solution...

Answer (score 0):

Use an ActionScript decompiler and inspect the output for networking calls (for instance, any references to `flash.net.Socket`).

The decompiler I had good experience with: https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler

While their main package is a GUI application, the code is open source so you could build a batch tool around their library. Note that this library supports "disassemble only" mode where you will see the imports but won't waste time on decompiling any method bodies. Checking the imports for `flash.net.Socket` is likely enough diligence.

If you have dependencies between your libraries, you'll need to track them yourself. Unfortunately, this approach will lead to a lot of false positives, if the libraries are too generic (e.g., general utility library that does stuff with `Socket` but is also used for math).

Comment: To quote the issue `...we have really large number of them, so start/sniff would not work`. To start/run each one and sniff the network would be a long mission. There were some comments (in an older answer) where he mentioned it's thousands of SWF files.